# Same margin between cell uicollectionviewflowlayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I've been searching on **google** & stackoverflow for a while trying to accomplish a fairly simple action on my `UICollectionViewCells` but until now I've not been able to do it.

What I want to have is a `CollectionViewController` with two cells for each row. Each cell must have the same margin on top, left, bottom and right sides.

Until now what I have is:

[image]

The thing is that I want to have the same amount of margin in each side of the cell. That means that the `EdgeInsets` left and right both have to be 14 not 7..

I am not able to accomplish this.. I know that I'm missing something but I can't figure out what is.

I am using a `FlowLayout`, this is the code of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
fileprivate let phoneSectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 14.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 7.0)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let phoneHeight = 250
        let fixedWidth = 220

        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2 - (phoneSectionInsets.left + phoneSectionInsets.right)), height: CGFloat(phoneHeight))

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return phoneSectionInsets
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 14.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 14.0
}
```

If I set the edge insets from left and right to 14 then I have 14 margin on the right and left sides but in between cell I have 28..

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: May this help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654129/how-to-change-space-between-cells-in-uicollectionview/35654505#35654505

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872308/3411787) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cross check your code in sizeforitem

```
fileprivate let phoneSectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 14.0, left: 14.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 14.0)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let phoneHeight = 250
        let fixedWidth = 220

        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.size.width -  (phoneSectionInsets.left + phoneSectionInsets.right + 14/*item spacing */))/2.0, height: CGFloat(phoneHeight))

}
```

while calculating item width you need to consider left and right margin along with item in between spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing exactly the same thing in my application with this code :

```
    let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-30)*0.5
    collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize =  CGSize(width: width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5)
    collectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10,left: 10,bottom: 10,right: 10)
    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
```

> Note: I have taken the outlet of the flow layout instead using delegate methods.

Change the cell size accroding to your need.

Comment: I haven't try it you solution but I think it will work. I marked the above answer as correct because it is a fix over my implementation (and it works). Thank you so much