# How to limit collection view spacing based on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am setting the size for a collectionView's cells depending on the device's screen size via the function (retrieved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872001/uicollectionview-cell-spacing-based-on-device-screen-size/28872308)). However, I am having a problem with the cell spacing.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: (width - 10)/3, height: (width - 10)/3) // width & height are the same to make a square cell
}
```

**iPhone SE 2** *Displays well*
[Collection view on iPhone SE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw1GB.png)

**iPhone XS Max** *Too much spacing*
[Collection view on iPhone XS Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfDTW.png)

**Collection view storyboard**
[image: Size inspector configuration]

**Storyboard constraints** *Showing collectionView constraints to View*
[image]

Comment: I don't think the size of your cells is the issue, but rather the spacing is. Could you please show your implementation of the other `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods?

Comment: @DávidPásztor please find the size inspector information added in the question.

Comment: That all looks fine, are you sure you aren't overriding these programatically? Another possible issue could be using `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` to calculate `width`, I'd suggest replacing that to use the safe area. `let width = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width`.

Comment: issue is with sizeForItemAt method implementation...I update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below codes :

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0) // up to you
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the minimum line space, since you allocate space for line of cell when defining cell width, It is safe to set minimum line space to zero.

Use one of the following method

1. In code
   extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {

   ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 0
   }
   ```

**OR**

1. In StoryBoard

[image]

**AND**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let numberOfCells = 3
let leftSectionInset: CGFloat = 30          //set the size u have given
let rightSectionInset: CGFloat = 30         //set the size u have given
let cellSpace: CGFloat = 20                 // set any space u want between cells
let space: CGFloat = leftSectionInset + rightSectionInset + (cellSpace * CGFloat((numberOfCells - 1)) )
let cellWidth: CGFloat = (width - space)/CGFloat(numberOfCells)

return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
```

}

Comment: Thank you @Yodagama. I implemented your code and size inspector data but the cells are still stuck to each other.

Comment: did you set all sizes to zero ( since you are giving size by code ) ? and the estimate cell size to "none " like in the screen shot ?

Comment: Yes I did, but it displays all cells to the left edge of the screen and they're all stuck to each other.

Comment: give some values for section insect left and section insect right, as well as  use the given value in the "sizeForItemAt" method.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what do you mean by use the given value in the sizeforItemAt method? Doesn't the method do that automatically?

Comment: No. that method which I have shown in the end of my answer is not getting the values from storyboard so that you have to give those values ( I have commented out in those places, so you need to set the values which you have given in the storyboard to those variables.

Comment: Could you please update your answer so I can have a clearer understanding of what to do? I put the storyboard values at 0, and put the actual ones in the code, but it's not working.